How to read inner-tube size ranges on Conti tubes?
I'm a bit confused by the sizes that are listed on the Conti tube boxes.
E.g. 28'' Tour All, which I have lying around, lists:

32-622 ▶ 47-622
28 x 1.5 ▶ 28 x 1.75


But as I understand so far wheel sizes 32mm - 47mm should match 1.25'' - 1,85'' when here they are paired with 1.5 - 1.75.
Practicalities: Can I put these on my 35-622 / 28x1.35 Gravel Bike wheels or not? (The presta valve is the correct one.)
Specifically, as noted above, I'm confused by the seemingly mismatched width specs of ETRTO/ISO vs. Decimal/English on this "All" model.
Because Conti also has a "slim" version of this innertube:

28-622 ▶ 37-622
28 x 1.1 ▶ 28 x 1.5

where my wheel would fit into both dimensions, but here, the dimensions seem to actually match: 28mm ~ 1.1'' and 37mm ~ 1.46''


Hi and welcome to the site. As it stands I see three different questions here posted as one: "How to read the size ranges?", "The ranges given in mm and the ones in inches seemingly don't match, his can that be?", and "Can I use this tube in my specific tire?". Could you please clarify which is the question you're seeking an answer to?

@BenediktBauer - The how-to-read and the they-dont-match are basically two sides of the same question (personally I don't feel they would have distinct useful answers). The "specific" thing I mostly added as practical background. Hope this helps.

Regarding the mismatch between ISO and decimal I think it is either a mistake by conti or due to the fact that decimal notation does not have anything to do with reality. 28" tyres are not 28" in diameter and 1.5" width are rarely 1.5" wide. The bottom line is: this mismatch leaves me as puzzled as you.

TLDR:
Yes, you can. This inner tube is correct size for your wheels/tyres. I decided this based on your stated tyre size of 35-622  which is within specified 32-622 to 47-622 range.
For more details and how to read sizing notations ... read on.
On getting it slightly wrong
Butyl inner tubes are very forgiving in getting sizing a little bit off. If you have a tube of a wrong size but you can physically fit it inside your tyre without having to stretch or fold it, you are usually OK.
Other forum members may disagree, but my personal experience to date confirms it.
Getting a tyre of correct size to fit your rim could be a minefield, but that is out of scope of this question.
Getting it right / rule of thumb
Where possible stick with ISO/ETRTO sizing specs. These are becoming more and more universally adopted and cause least confusion.
Where not possible to use ISO spec, find the spec that looks most like the one on your tyre and aim for an inner tube that lands withing acceptable range.
Do not confuse decimal and fractional sizing. Numbers may be mathematically equal but mean completely different thing. For example: 28x1/2 is not the same as 25x1.5.
Examples from your picture
ETRTO/ISO

In a nutshell: Two numbers. First one means inflated tyre width, second one means bead seat deamter.
Stands for European Tyre and Rim Technical Organization and is not limited to just bicycle tyres. This notation is also applied to other pneumatic tyres.
This standard is also refered to as ISO
This is the only standard that takes tyre inner diameter / bead seat diameter into account. Other standards only describe tyre outer diameter and width plus sometimes height.
Read more here:
https://www.sheldonbrown.com/tire-sizing.html#isoetrto
Also:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_5775
Decimal/English

In a nutshell: First number is supposed to be nominal inflated tyre outer diameter in inches. Second number is inflated tyre width in inches
Key point here is that numbers mean very little. For example 28" tyre may be nowhere near 28" in diameter.
Fractional/Imperial

In a nutshell: First number is nominal inflated tyre outer diameter in inches. Middle number if present is inflated tyre height in inches. Last number is inflated tyre width in inches
Just like with decimal numbers mean very little. For example 28" tyre may be nowhere near 28" in diameter.
French

In a nutshell: first number is nominal inflated tyre outer diamter in mm, second number is inflated tyre width in mm and letter code (A~30mm,B~32mm,C~39mm,D~?mm) used to mean tyre height, but is largely meaningless now.
And again, diameter measurement in this standard is largely meaningless. According to this notation 700x47C and 700x32C should have the same tyre outer diameter but they usually don't.
Also 700 tyres are usually not 700mm in diameter. It is not uncommong for them to be 710mm or more. Same goes for 650 tyres.
Final thoughts
I am not sure why in your example Continental chose to write some specs on white bacground and some on grey. I can only guess this is a formatting choice for better readability.

Thanks. I found another box in my bike drawer SCHWALBE SCHLAUCH NR. 17 and ended up using that one. (The specs seem to fit a bit better.) I guess the Conti would also have fit.

I have also edited the question to highlight my main confusing of the mismatched widths.
